# Is it possible to close IE in Kiosk Mode without a comfirmation alert?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, kiosk-mode

I can open a Chrome browser window in **kiosk mode** from the command line...

`start chrome --kiosk "http://example.com/"`

...and then close the page with a `<button>` that simply runs `window.close();` in a JavaScript event.

But when I start IE in kiosk mode...

`start iexplore -k "http://example.com"`

...and click the same button, I get the alert:

> The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window. Do you want to close this window? [Yes /No]

Is there some way -- maybe with JavaScript or [IE command line options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx) -- to avoid the alert and get IE to act the same as Chrome?

Comment: There is.  Let me find it.  Be right back.

Answer (score 1):

Have your javascript function do this:

```
window.open('','_self').close()
```

Explanation:
IE won't let you close, without warning, a window you didn't open.  This function opens a blank window that overwrites the current window.  And since you now own it, the next part of the function closes it without issue.